# VOIP compatibility on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

We had a situation where we wanted to build Windows Phone app with minimum compatible version Windows Phone 8.1. It makes uses of VOIP calls over 3G / 4G and Wifi.

I am unable to find whether Windows Phone 8.1 has full support for VOIP calls or not. Can anyone redirect me to right documentation or guidance if WP8.1 supports VOIP?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this below link for VoIP capabilities of Windows Phone 8 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx

I'm trying to develop a VoIP application based on these solutions:
https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/boghe & https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-wp

Answer (score 0):

Check these. I think it does.

[ChatterBox-VoIP-WP81](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ChatterBox-VoIP-WP81-64921ad4) 
[Upgrade calls from cellular to VoIP in a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn643752(v=vs.105).aspx)
[understanding-and-using-voip-support-in-windows-phone-8](http://www.developer.com/ws/understanding-and-using-voip-support-in-windows-phone-8.html)